# Jolt transform several object to array with new field name

Tags: java, json, jolt

I'am new using jolt tool and i wonder if there a way to take several json objects and put them to an array with a new field named as follows:

***Input*** :

```json
{
  "userId": 1,
  "age": 20,
  "desc1": "value desc1",
  "desc2": "value desc2",
  "desc3": "value desc3"
}
```

***JSON spec*** :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "userId": "ID",
      "age": "age",
      "*": "additionalInformation"
    }
  }
]
```

***Expected result*** :

```json
{
  "ID": 1,
  "age": 20,
  "additionalInformation": [
    {
      "code": "desc1",
      "value": "value desc1"
    },
    {
      "code": "desc2",
      "value": "value desc2"
    },
    {
      "code": "desc3",
      "value": "value desc3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Using the spec above i can only obtain ***this result*** :

```json
{
  "ID": 1,
  "test": 20,
  "additionalInformation": [
    "value desc1",
    "value desc2",
    "value desc3"
  ]
}
```

Any suggestion what i have missed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **$** and **@** wildcards for **code** and **value**, respectively while combining the elements under common factor by using **&.** as prefixes for them in the first step. Then combine elements other than **ID** and **age** within the same array in the last step such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "userId": "ID",
      "age": "age",
      "*": {
        "$": "&.code",
        "@": "&.value"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "ID": "&",
      "age": "&",
      "*": "additionalInformation[]"
    }
  }
]
```

[image]

**Edit**(*due to the comment*) : If you need to pick some individual elements such as **desc1** and **desc3** rather than all(**"*"**), then replace the first spec with following

```json
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "userId": "ID",
      "age": "age",
      "desc1|desc3": {
        "$": "&.code",
        "@": "&.value"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Barbaros, it is exactly what i was expecting. However if we had to pick only specifics fields to put them in the array (e.g desc1 and desc3) the wilcard can't do that since it takes all others available fields

Comment: Appreciate your help. i ended up by using an other way found on the documentation that fit also my need however i still have some difficulty removing null values generated in the output as mentioned in the screen above. Any suggestion ?

Comment: Hi @Yawyaw1 . Let's keep this question by reverting the last update as it is as already been answered, and ask another one along with adding the new spec please.